# AWS Amplify - Lerna Monorepo - Can't install private github package

Tags: aws-amplify, lerna, github-packages

I am having trouble installing a private github package with my lerna monorepo using AWS Amplify hosting.

I have updated the build settings to create a .npmrc file at the time of build and install the package in the preBuild stage, however when it begins the build stage it cannot find the module.

**Reproduction steps**

1. Set up amplify hosting for react app as monorepo (Lerna)
2. Update build settings to create .npmrc and install package
3. Run build

**Build settings**

```
version: 1
applications:
  - backend:
      phases:
        build:
          commands:
            - '# Execute Amplify CLI with the helper script'
            - amplifyPush --simple
    frontend:
      phases:
        preBuild:
          commands:
            - yarn install --frozen-lockfile
            - echo -e "always-auth=true\n@apptractive:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/\n//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=$NPM_AUTH_TOKEN" > .npmrc
            - yarn add @apptractive/shared
            - yarn add @apptractive/design-system-web
        build:
          commands:
            - yarn run build
      artifacts:
        baseDirectory: build
        files:
          - '**/*'
      cache:
        paths:
          - node_modules/**/*
    appRoot: packages/backoffice-app
```

**Error that shows**
[image: Error that displays]

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found that I needed to build the packages within the build script as they were being imported from the monorepo itself and not github packages.

Probably can be done with a better approach, but this got me over the line for now

```
version: 1
applications:
  - backend:
      phases:
        build:
          commands:
            - '# Execute Amplify CLI with the helper script'
            - amplifyPush --simple
    frontend:
      phases:
        preBuild:
          commands:
            - yarn global add lerna
            - npm config set registry https://npm.pkg.github.com
            - npm config set always-auth true
            - npm config set //https://npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${NPM_AUTH_TOKEN}
            - lerna bootstrap --include-dependencies
            - cd ../shared && yarn build
            - cd ../design-web && yarn build
        build:
          commands:
            - yarn run build
      artifacts:
        baseDirectory: build
        files:
          - '**/*'
      cache:
        paths:
          - node_modules/**/*
    appRoot: packages/backoffice-app
```